# Progress Bar and system animation settings off

Tags: android

I am beginner on Android programming. I'm trying to show a circle progress bar on my application, but the progress does not show on Android 7.0 phone, or on other phone with Android 8.0 shows an circle arrow not spinning. 
After some long research on the Internet I've found that happens because of animations disabled in Developer Settings. I am not a fan of window animation, transitions...
Is there any solution to this problem? Some settings in my application to enable animation for progress bar?

As requested, I've added some code. But there is nothing special with my code.
I've used Android Studio to generate an empty application. Minimum SDK 21, target SDK 28.

My application layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/Progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

My application main activity:

```
package ro.essd.testprogbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

From Developer Options only Animator Duration Scale does something. If is disabled, the result is bellow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGfug.png)

If the above setting is set to 1x then the progress bar is spinning.

Thank you!

Comment: Would be great if you share some code of what you have done already.

Comment: I've edited the post with the code. Thank you.